# Unable to compile Electron App due to incorrect parser

Tags: typescript, vue.js, electron, vuejs3

So I'm trying to get a simple electron app up and running with Vue 3 and Typescript. Currently, I have run the following commands that allow an electron + Vue 3 app to run successfully:

```
vue create app_name
cd .\app_name\
vue add electron-builder
npm run electron:serve
```

After that, things go downhill when I try to implement typescript. I tried to change the `<script>` to `<script lang="ts">` and the app crashes with an error about "Parsing error: No Babel config file detected". ***If anyone has any insight as to what it takes to get it working at this point, please let me know!***

**As far as troubleshooting steps I've tried:**

I tried installing babel-eslint, @babel/core, @babel/eslint-parser + I created a .eslintrc.js file. Then I got a bunch of errors about:

```
Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/parser'
```

So then I tried installing some packages @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin, @typescript-eslint/parser, @vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli/plugin-eslint, @vue/cli-service, eslint-plugin-vue, and typescript a second time just to check my sanity. After this I began getting odd errors about my string literals not terminating and it was highlighting a basic `<div>test</div>` I had in the template saying that was not compliant.

I also tried following this guide, but I could not get it to work: https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#what-is-the-use-the-latest-vue-eslint-parser-error

I also tried moving the installed app directory to the root directory of VSCode because a few places online mentioned that might be an issue, made no difference in the errors.

At this point I began changing up the eslintrc.js file to try to choose a correct parser, and it kept generating odd errors about my test vue file. As it currently sits:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaVersion: 8,
    extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    }
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended'
  ],
  overrides: [{
    files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
    rules: {
      'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    }
  }]
}
```

Current Error:

```
  5:1  error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", null, " hey "))
| }

ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true) 3:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"
|
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", null, " hey "))
| }
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true 1:0-196 1:0-196
 @ ./src/App.vue 1:0-72 8:68-74 18:71-20:3 19:29-35 18:2-20:4
 @ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 3:10-13

ERROR in [eslint]
C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\Hylio\dev\electron_app\src\App.vue
  5:1  error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

And the code it's complaining about:

```
<template>
  <div> hey </div>
</template>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!! If it's easier to scrap this and start over, I am welcome to that as well.

Comment: @kenWhite I've updated the title! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would happily recommend you start here: https://github.com/electron-vite/electron-vite-vue

This is not an answer, I haven't been able to add a comment yet, this is just my sharing.

Comment: I know this isn't an exact answer, but it worked perfectly! Got Vue 3 + Typescript + Vite up and running in no time at all. I was able to then painlessly migrate my small app via copy/pasting. Thank you!!!